# NULL Values not Being Returned

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where I am running a query again tables MEMBERS, MEMBERUDFS, and MEMERUDFSETUPS. Where MEMBER UDFs are User Defined Fields that are created by the system admin to store data about customers in customizable fields. The UDFSETUPS table defines the configurable fields and MEMBERUDFS stores the values of those fields if they exist.

The issue I am running into is when I pull data back, I am not getting the rows for entries that have a UDF with an ID of 17 (MEMBERUDFS.udfid = '17') that do not have an entry or are null. I tried Left Joins but it did not seem to help.

```
SELECT MEMBERS.scancode, MEMBERS.fname, MEMBERS.lname, MEMBERS.datejoin, MEMBERS.entrydate
     , MEMBERS.relationship, MEMBERUDFS.udfvalue
FROM MEMBERS 
LEFT OUTER JOINMEMBERUDFS 
  ON MEMBERS.memid = MEMBERUDFS.memid 
INNER JOIN MEMBERUDFSETUPS 
  ON MEMBERUDFS.udfid = MEMBERUDFSETUPS.udfid
WHERE (MEMBERS.siteid = @rvSite) 
  AND (MEMBERS.status = 'A') 
  AND (MEMBERS.relationship = 'M') 
  AND (MEMBERUDFS.udfid = '17') 
  AND (MEMBERS.datejoin BETWEEN @rvStartDate AND @rvEndDate) 
  AND (MEMBERS.mtypeid NOT IN (5, 6, 7, 11, 14, 31)) 
   OR (MEMBERS.siteid = @rvSite) 
  AND (MEMBERS.relationship = 'P') 
  AND (MEMBERUDFS.udfid = '17') 
  AND (MEMBERS.entrydate BETWEEN @rvStartDate AND @rvEndDate)
```

Comment: You still have an `INNER JOIN` to `MemberUDFSetups`

Comment: `memberudf.udfid` in the where clause is causing them to be excluded you need to move that limit to the join or check for nulls in there where clause on that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the limit on the JoinMemberUDFS to the join or your nulls get excluded.

**Preferred method move filter to join criteria**

```
SELECT MEMBERS.scancode, MEMBERS.fname, MEMBERS.lname, MEMBERS.datejoin, MEMBERS.entrydate
     , MEMBERS.relationship, MEMBERUDFS.udfvalue
FROM MEMBERS 
LEFT JOIN MEMBERUDFS 
  ON MEMBERS.memid = MEMBERUDFS.memid 
 AND  MEMBERUDFS.udfid = '17'
LEFT JOIN MEMBERUDFSETUPS 
  ON MEMBERUDFS.udfid = MEMBERUDFSETUPS.udfid
WHERE (MEMBERS.siteid = @rvSite
  AND MEMBERS.status = 'A'
  AND MEMBERS.relationship = 'M' 
  AND MEMBERS.datejoin BETWEEN @rvStartDate AND @rvEndDate
  AND MEMBERS.mtypeid NOT IN (5, 6, 7, 11, 14, 31))
   OR (MEMBERS.siteid = @rvSite
  AND MEMBERS.relationship = 'P'
  AND MEMBERS.entrydate BETWEEN @rvStartDate AND @rvEndDate)
```

Not preferred handle when it's null and ensure it returns true for the evaluation

```
SELECT MEMBERS.scancode, MEMBERS.fname, MEMBERS.lname, MEMBERS.datejoin, MEMBERS.entrydate
     , MEMBERS.relationship, MEMBERUDFS.udfvalue
FROM MEMBERS 
LEFT OUTER JOINMEMBERUDFS 
  ON MEMBERS.memid = MEMBERUDFS.memid 

INNER JOIN MEMBERUDFSETUPS 
  ON MEMBERUDFS.udfid = MEMBERUDFSETUPS.udfid
WHERE (MEMBERS.siteid = @rvSite
  AND MEMBERS.status = 'A'
  AND MEMBERS.relationship = 'M' 
  AND MEMBERS.datejoin BETWEEN @rvStartDate AND @rvEndDate
  AND MEMBERS.mtypeid NOT IN (5, 6, 7, 11, 14, 31)
  AND (MEMBERUDFS.udfid = '17' or MEMBERUDFS.udfid is null)
   OR (MEMBERS.siteid = @rvSite
  AND MEMBERS.relationship = 'P'
  AND MEMBERS.entrydate BETWEEN @rvStartDate AND @rvEndDate)
  AND (MEMBERUDFS.udfid = '17' or MEMBERUDFS.udfid is null)
```

Comment: I think this will  kill the left INNER JOIN MEMBERUDFSETUPS ON MEMBERUDFS.udfid = MEMBERUDFSETUPS.udfid.  There is a reference to MEMBERUDFSETUPS.udfid

Comment: yeah, may need to left join the memberudfsetups to be safe.

Comment: Thank you xQbert and Paparazzi!!!! Once I added the Left Outer Join per Paparazzi's suggestions I retrieved the results I was looking for. Thank you!!!